# Why does cbind with pasted colnames throw an error versus manual entry of column names?

Tags: r

I'm summing many numeric variables in a dataframe called "thresh" using the aggregate function. When I implement the code with column names entered manually, the code works properly, but when I use paste to add a lot of column names, it throws the following error:

> Error in Summary.factor(c(46L, 1L, 12L, 23L, 34L, 45L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
>   :    ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors In addition: Warning message: In
>   cbind(noquote(paste0(paste0("Tabove", 0:50, "C"), sep = ",")),  :
>   number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)

The paste code that throws the error:

```
stage1sum <- aggregate(formula = cbind(noquote(paste0(paste0("Tabove",0:50,"C"),sep=",")),
                                  ppt_cm) ~ Veg_s1 + Location, data=thresh, FUN = sum)
```

The manual code that works properly:

```
stage1sum <- aggregate(formula = cbind(Tabove0C, Tabove1C, Tabove2C, Tabove3C,
                                  ppt_cm) ~ Veg_s1 + Location, data=thresh, FUN = sum)
```

I'm using R version 3.4.0 and RStudio version 1.0.143. All of my columns are numeric within the aggregation. Can anyone help me understand why this error is being produced?

Comment: You ca do this easily by subsetting i.e. `aggregate(.~ Veg_s1 + Location, data = thresh["Veg_s1", "Location", paste0("Tabove",0:50,"C"))], FUN = sum)`

Comment: Formulas are special. If you want to convert a string you've constructed into a formula, build the entire formula as a string and then use `as.formula`.

Comment: To echo @Gregor's comment:  a string that looks like a formula and a formula are different things.

Comment: I used @akrun's solution above, but also tested Gregor's which also works. Thank you all for helping me better understand this.